# Bank account kata with F# MailboxProcessor slow

Tags: f#, mailboxprocessor

I've coded the "classical" [bank account kata](https://exercism.org/tracks/fsharp/exercises/bank-account) with F# `MailboxProcessor` to be thread safe. But when I try to parallelize adding a transaction to an account, it's very slow very quick: 10 parallel calls are responsive (2ms), 20 not (9 seconds)! *(See last test `Account can be updated from multiple threads` beneath)*

Since `MailboxProcessor` supports 30 million messages per second (see [theburningmonk's article](https://theburningmonk.com/2012/03/f-how-many-messages-can-you-post-to-a-f-agent-in-one-second/)), where the problem comes from?

```ml
// -- Domain ----

type Message =
    | Open of AsyncReplyChannel<bool>
    | Close of AsyncReplyChannel<bool>
    | Balance of AsyncReplyChannel<decimal option>
    | Transaction of decimal * AsyncReplyChannel<bool>

type AccountState = { Opened: bool; Transactions: decimal list }

type Account() =
    let agent = MailboxProcessor<Message>.Start(fun inbox ->
        let rec loop (state: AccountState) =
            async {
                let! message = inbox.Receive()
                match message with
                | Close channel ->
                    channel.Reply state.Opened
                    return! loop { state with Opened = false }
                | Open channel ->
                    printfn $"Opening"
                    channel.Reply (not state.Opened)
                    return! loop { state with Opened = true }
                | Transaction (tran, channel) ->
                    printfn $"Adding transaction {tran}, nb = {state.Transactions.Length}"
                    channel.Reply true
                    return! loop { state with Transactions = tran :: state.Transactions }
                | Balance channel ->
                    let balance =
                        if state.Opened then
                            state.Transactions |> List.sum |> Some
                        else
                            None
                    balance |> channel.Reply
                    return! loop state
            }
        loop { Opened = false; Transactions = [] }
    )

    member _.Open () = agent.PostAndReply(Open)
    member _.Close () = agent.PostAndReply(Close)
    member _.Balance () = agent.PostAndReply(Balance)
    member _.Transaction (transaction: decimal) =
        agent.PostAndReply(fun channel -> Transaction (transaction, channel))
```

```ml
// -- API ----

let mkBankAccount = Account

let openAccount (account: Account) =
    match account.Open() with
    | true -> Some account
    | false -> None

let closeAccount (account: Account option) =
    account |> Option.bind (fun a ->
        match a.Close() with
        | true -> Some a
        | false -> None)

let updateBalance transaction (account: Account option) =
    account |> Option.bind (fun a ->
        match a.Transaction(transaction) with
        | true -> Some a
        | false -> None)

let getBalance (account: Account option) =
    account |> Option.bind (fun a -> a.Balance())
```

```ml
// -- Tests ----

let should_equal expected actual =
    if expected = actual then
        Ok expected
    else
        Error (expected, actual)

let should_not_equal expected actual =
    if expected <> actual then
        Ok expected
    else
        Error (expected, actual)

let ``Returns empty balance after opening`` =
    let account = mkBankAccount() |> openAccount
    getBalance account |> should_equal (Some 0.0m)

let ``Check basic balance`` =
    let account = mkBankAccount() |> openAccount
    let openingBalance = account |> getBalance
    let updatedBalance =
        account
        |> updateBalance 10.0m
        |> getBalance
    openingBalance |> should_equal (Some 0.0m),
    updatedBalance |> should_equal (Some 10.0m)

let ``Balance can increment or decrement`` =
    let account = mkBankAccount() |> openAccount
    let openingBalance = account |> getBalance
    let addedBalance =
        account
        |> updateBalance 10.0m
        |> getBalance
    let subtractedBalance =
        account
        |> updateBalance -15.0m
        |> getBalance
    openingBalance |> should_equal (Some 0.0m),
    addedBalance |> should_equal (Some 10.0m),
    subtractedBalance |> should_equal (Some -5.0m)

let ``Account can be closed`` =
    let account =
        mkBankAccount()
        |> openAccount
        |> closeAccount
    getBalance account |> should_equal None,
    account |> should_not_equal None

#time
let ``Account can be updated from multiple threads`` =
    let account =
        mkBankAccount()
        |> openAccount
    let updateAccountAsync =
        async {
            account
            |> updateBalance 1.0m
            |> ignore
        }
    let nb = 10 //  10 is quick (2ms), 20 is so long (9s)
    updateAccountAsync
    |> List.replicate nb
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> ignore
    getBalance account |> should_equal (Some (decimal nb))
#time
```

Comment: I don't have much experience using mailbox processors, but I think one possible issue is that you're waiting synchronously on each transaction via `PostAndReply`. I think this is going to make it difficult to queue a large number of transactions.

Comment: I tried PostAndAsyncReply instead of PostAndReply and got 00:00:00.053 for 50 transactions. Obviously the calling threads having to wait synchronously for their replies rather than asynchronously is greatly slowing things down, though probably someone with a better understanding of the internals can post a full explanation.

Comment: @BrianBerns that's a plausible explanation, consider adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your code don't uses Async all the way up.

Your Account class has the method `Open`, `Close`, `Balance` and `Transaction` and you use a `AsyncReplyChannel` but
you use `PostAndReply` to send the message. This means: You send a message to the MailboxProcessor with a channel to reply. But, at this point, the method waits Synchronously to finish.

Even with `Async.Parallel` and multiple threads it can mean a lot of threads lock themsels. If you change
all your Methods to use `PostAndAsyncReply` then your problem goes away.

There are two other performance optimization that can speed up performance, but are not critical in your example.

1. Calling the Length of a list is bad. To calculate the length of a list, you must go through the whole list. You only
   use this in Transaction to print the length, but consider if the transaction list becomes longer. You alway must go through
   the whole list, whenever you add a transaction. This will be O(N) of your transaction list.
2. The same goes for calling (List.sum). You have to calculate the current Balance whenever you call Balance. Also O(N).

As you have a MailboxProcessor, you also could calculate those two values instead of completly recalculating those values again and again.Thus, they become O(1) operations.

On top, i would change the `Open`, `Close` and `Transaction` messages to return nothing, as in my Opinion, it doesn't make sense that they return anything. Your examples even makes me confused of what the `bool` return
values even mean.

In the `Close` message you return `state.Opened` before you set it to false. Why?

In the `Open` message you return the negated `state.Opened`. How you use it later it just looks wrong.

If there is more meaning behind the `bool` please make a distinct Discriminated Union out of it, that describes the purpose of what it returns.

You used an `option<Acount>` throughout your code, i removed it, as i don't see any purpose of it.

Anyway, here is a full example, of how i would write your code that don't have the speed problems.

```
type Message =
    | Open
    | Close
    | Balance     of AsyncReplyChannel<decimal option>
    | Transaction of decimal

type AccountState = {
    Opened:             bool
    Transactions:       decimal list
    TransactionsLength: int
    CurrentBalance:     decimal
}

type Account() =
    let agent = MailboxProcessor<Message>.Start(fun inbox ->
        let rec loop (state: AccountState) = async {
            match! inbox.Receive() with
            | Close ->
                printfn "Closing"
                return! loop { state with Opened = false }
            | Open ->
                printfn "Opening"
                return! loop { state with Opened = true }
            | Transaction tran ->
                let l = state.TransactionsLength + 1
                printfn $"Adding transaction {tran}, nb = {l}"

                if state.Opened then
                    return! loop {
                        state with
                            Transactions       = tran :: state.Transactions
                            TransactionsLength = l
                            CurrentBalance     = state.CurrentBalance + tran
                    }
                else
                    return! loop state
            | Balance channel ->
                if   state.Opened
                then channel.Reply (Some state.CurrentBalance)
                else channel.Reply  None
                return! loop state
        }

        let defaultAccount = {
            Opened             = false
            Transactions       = []
            TransactionsLength = 0
            CurrentBalance     = 0m
        }
        loop defaultAccount
    )

    member _.Open        ()          = agent.Post(Open)
    member _.Close       ()          = agent.Post(Close)
    member _.Balance     ()          = agent.PostAndAsyncReply(Balance)
    member _.Transaction transaction = agent.Post(Transaction transaction)

(* Test *)

let should_equal expected actual =
    if expected = actual then
        Ok expected
    else
        Error (expected, actual)

(* --- API --- *)

let mkBankAccount = Account

(* Opens the Account *)
let openAccount  (account: Account) =
    account.Open ()

(* Closes the Account *)
let closeAccount (account: Account) =
    account.Close ()

(* Updates Account *)
let updateBalance transaction (account: Account) =
    account.Transaction(transaction)

(* Gets the current Balance *)
let getBalance (account: Account) =
    account.Balance ()

#time
let ``Account can be updated from multiple threads`` =
    let account = mkBankAccount ()
    openAccount account

    let updateBalanceAsync = async {
        updateBalance 1.0m account
    }

    let nb = 50

    List.replicate nb updateBalanceAsync
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> ignore

    Async.RunSynchronously (async {
        let! balance = getBalance account
        printfn "Balance is %A should be (Some %f)" balance (1.0m * decimal nb)
    })
#time
```